# Representing norm of a vector using orthogonal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

If $e_1,...,e_n, \eta$ are vectors in $V$, the first $n$ of which are a ONB, is it true that $$\| \eta \|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle e_i, \eta \rangle^2?$$

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Could you give a reason? I have never studied linear algebra, but need this result. What definition gives this result exactly?

Comment: Assuming you are over $\Bbb R$. Since $(e_i\,:\,i=1,\cdots, n)$ is a basis, we have $$\eta=\sum_{j=1}^n \eta_je_j$$Since the $e_i$-s are ortho**normal**, we have $$\langle e_i,\,\eta\rangle=\sum_{j=1}^n\langle e_i,\eta_je_j\rangle=\eta_i$$ So $$\langle\eta,\eta\rangle=\left\langle\sum_{i=1}^n\langle e_i,\eta\rangle e_i,\,\sum_{j=1}^n\langle e_j,\eta\rangle e_j\right\rangle=\sum_{i,j}\langle e_i, \eta\rangle\langle e_j, \eta\rangle \langle e_i, e_j\rangle$$ and the tems wit $i\ne j$ cancel out by orthogonality

Comment: @G.Sassatelli You should write that up as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\scal}[2]{\left\langle{#1},\,{#2}\right\rangle}$
Since $(e_i\,:\,i=1,\cdots,n)$ is a basis, there exist (unique) $\eta_1,\cdots,\eta_n\in \Bbb R$ such that $$\eta=\eta_1e_1+\cdots+\eta_ne_n$$

Since the $e_i$-s are orthonormal, it holds $$\scal{e_i}{e_j}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }i=j\\0&\text{if }i\ne j\end{cases}$$ therefore the $\eta_i$-s can be recovered thanks to the scalar product:
\begin{align}\scal{e_i}{\eta}&=\scal{e_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_je_j}=&\text{bilinearity}\\&=\sum_{j=1}^n\eta_j\scal{e_i}{e_j}=&\text{orthonormality}\\&=\eta_i\end{align}

So $\eta=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\scal{e_j}{\eta}e_j$.

Now, by bilinearity \begin{align}\lVert\eta\rVert^2=\scal{\eta}{\eta}&=\scal{\sum_{i=1}^n\scal{e_i}{\eta}e_i}{\sum_{j=1}^n\scal{e_j}{\eta}e_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n\scal{e_i}\eta\scal{e_j}\eta\scal{e_i}{e_j}=\\&=\sum_{i=1}^n\scal{e_i}{\eta}^2\end{align}